# C# Multiple Generic List<t> - Combining Them?

Tags: c#, list, generic-list

#### Scenario:

I have a generic list of Audits and a generic list of AuditImages. These two lists have been compiled from database tables. As a result of this, ONE AuditImage can have MANY Audits. As you will see below, the classes that the tables map to are joined by a foreign key relationship "ImageID" when they are in the database, however once the data is extracted to lists in code, there is no "PHYSICAL JOIN".

#### Classes That DB Tables Map To:

```
public class AuditImage
{
    public Guid ImageID { get; set; }
    public string LowResUrl { get; set; }
}

public class Audit
{
    public Guid AuditID { get; set; }
    public Guid ImageID { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
}
```

#### The Problem:

I now want to compile a list of "Trail" objects by extracting the data from each list and combining it on "Audit.ImageID == AuditImage.ImageID", into a new list.

```
public class Trail
{
    public Guid ImageID { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public string LowResUrl { get; set; }
}
```

(The above essentially combines the "LowResUrl" field with each Audit based on the ImageID being the same.)

#### The Question:

How should I go about doing this!? I had thought about using foreach loops and linq to create a new list of trail objects but I can't quite think of exactly how I would go about doing this?!

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This smells of bad design from the get-go. Why are you associating classes with ID's, instead of putting instances of AuditImage onto your Audit instances?

Comment: Annoying Silverlight Application design with messy server side code.......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could do

```
var trails = from audit in audits
   join image in auditImages on audit.ImageId equals image.ImageId
   select new Trail { ImageID = audit.ImageId, CreatedDate = audit.CreatedDate,
                      CreatedBy = audit.CreatedBy, Comment = audit.Comment,
                      LowResUrl = image.LowResUrl };
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the Intersect extension method on List: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb910215.aspx

I also think you should review your design and introduce a common interface IAudit or something similar.

Comment: How should intersect solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This could work.......

```
public List<JobImageAudit> CombineForAuditTrail()
        {
            var result = from a in auditList
                         join ai in imageList
                         on a.ImageID equals ai.ImageID
                         //into ait // note grouping        
                         select new JobImageAudit
                         {
                             JobID = a.JobID,
                             ImageID = a.ImageID.Value,
                             CreatedBy = a.CreatedBy,
                             CreatedDate = a.CreatedDate,
                             Comment = a.Comment,
                             LowResUrl = ai.LowResUrl,

                         };
            return result.ToList();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably use the extension methods, just because I'm not very ease into linq:

```
IEnumerable<Trail> trailList = auditImageList.Join(
  auditList, 
  auditImageItem => auditImageItem.ImageId, 
  auditItem => auditItem.ImageId,
  (auditImageItem, auditItem) =>  new Trail() 
  {  
    LowResUrl = auditImageItem.LowResUrl,
    ImageID = auditImageItem.ImageId, 
    CreatedDate = auditItem.CreatedDate,
    CreatedBy = auditItem.CreatedBy, 
    Comment = auditItem.Comment,
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

This will solve the issue.. from var query just add to trail objects in loop

```
    var query = from auditImage in AuditImageList 
    join audit in AuditList 
on auditImage.ImageID equals audit.ImageID 
select new { ImageID= auditImage.ImageID, CreatedDate = audit.CreatedDate, CreatedBy = audit.CreatedBY, Comment = audit.Comment , LowResUrl = auditImage.LowResUrl }; 

foreach (var trail in query) { //Assign Values to trail object and add to list of trails }
```

Comment: Why not directly create Trails?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want:

Inner join (only display `AuditImage` if it has a `Audit`):

```
var innerJoin = from image in images
                join audit in audits on image.ImageID equals audit.ImageID
                select new { image.ImageID, AuditImageId = audit.ImageID };
```

Left join (display `AuditImage` even if it does not have a `Audit`):

```
var leftJoin = from image in images
               join audit in audits on image.ImageID equals audit.ImageID
               into auditCats
               from auditCat in auditCats.DefaultIfEmpty(new Audit())
               select new { image.ImageID, AuditImageId = auditCat.ImageID };
```

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two options.

First is do simple join:

```
var trails = Audits.Join(Images, a => a.ImageID, i => i.ImageID, (a, i) =>
    new Trail
    {
        Comment = a.Comment,
        CreatedBy = a.CreatedBy,
        CreatedDate = a.CreatedDate,
        ImageID = a.ImageID,
        LowResUrl = i.LowResUrl
    });
```

Second is to use sub-query:

```
var trails = Audits.Select(a =>
    new Trail
    {
        Comment = a.Comment,
        CreatedBy = a.CreatedBy,
        CreatedDate = a.CreatedDate,
        ImageID = a.ImageID,
        LowResUrl = Images.Single(i => i.ImageID == a.ImageID).LowResUrl
    });
```

Both should work fine if ImageID is unique but I personally like sub-query more because it looks more natural than join.